# How to redirect requests to a different URL with Nginx without changing the URL in the browser for subdomains

Tags: http, nginx, redirect, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite requests from a subdomain to a subfolder, so the URL stays as `subdomain.example.com` in the browser, but the content of `example.com/subdomain` is shown.

I have tried using the rewrite directive, but this redirects the user instead of changing the URL in the browser. How can I do this without changing the URL in the browser?

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
server {
    server_name subdomain.example.com;

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://example.com/subdomain/$1 permanent;
    }
}
```

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;

    location / {
        rewrite ^ /subdomain$request_uri last;
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using the
`proxy_pass` directive in Nginx. Here's how you can modify your configuration:

```
nginxserver {
    listen 80;
    server_name subdomain.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://example.com/subdomain;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response! This solved my issue 90%. So now the redirect happens, but instead of the URL being subdomain.example.com it becomes subdomain.example.com/subdomain